# IE8 opacity chops off background image

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, opacity

I have a small problem with IE8.

I have the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/H577j/

In this I have two `div` and a `h3`. The `h3` has got a background image and is at the same time shifted negatively with `margin`.
The `div` that the `h3` tag is inside has an opacity, made with both `filter`, `-ms-filter`, and `opacity`in CSS.
The opacity works fine in all browsers, however, in IE8 the background image of the `h3` tag is hidden.

Does IE8 chop off anything outside the box? Or is there something else wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the IE opacity filter. I noticed that when you apply a filter to a box in IE, it automatically chops everything inside the box that spans outside of the box.

Comment: With only `filter` it is the same. Without `filter` and `-ms-filter` I get no opacity in IE.

Comment: I also tried to use a dropshadow filter on a box, and inside that box I had a absolutely positioned element with negative top and right values. After removing the filter everything was fine.

Comment: here's the fiddle from my issue: http://jsfiddle.net/RTTkU/1/ when you open it in IE 7&8 you will notice the close button being chopped. after you remove the filter the close button won't get chopped. hope it helps.